# Best way to use multiple implementations of interface with Dependeny Injection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have seen some similar questions but I have yet to find a good solution for this from the interface all the way to the controller.

**My Problem:**

I have a few different kinds of applications that will require restarts, each has its own logic for restarting the application(SSH,API calls, etc.). I have set up an interface because although different logic, they all will need some similar functions. I have also created 3 classes, one for each app that implements that interface. where I am having issues is understanding the best way to keep the logic as abstracted from the controller as possible.

**Some Questions:**

Should I also be creating an Abstract class? 
Should this be one controller that handles all types and chooses the correct one?
do I simply inject the different classes into the controller?

**Code:**

`RestartInterface.php`

```
<?php  namespace Application\Service\Restart;

   interface RestartInterface {

       public function start();

       public function stop();

       public function restart();
   }
```

**example of implementing class:**

```
<?php namespace Application\Service\Restart\AppOne;

   use Application\Service\Restart\RestartInterface;

    class AppOneRestart implements RestartInterface {

       public function start() {

       }

       public function stop() {

       }

       public function restart() {

       } 

   }
```

How could I use a service provider to keep this as modular as possible?
What is the best practice in this situation, I would like to be able to use many or as little restart implementations as I want.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An abstract class is a way to create a base class you don't need your developers instantiating directly because, usually, there is still missing code from it, like, methods were not fully implemented. So you create an abstract which implements the common methods of your concrete restart classes

```
abstract class Restart {

   public function restart() {

   } 

}
```

And then you implement one by one of those classes extending your abstract and creating the missing methods:

```
class AppOneRestart extends Restart implements RestartInterface {

   public function start() {

   }

   public function stop() {

   }

}
```

### Option 1

If your whole application can use a single implementation of it and you just need the ability to swap from one to another, because your business somehow changed, a simple binding will do the trick:

```
App::bind('RestartInterface', 'AppOneRestart');
```

### Option 2

If during a request you might need one or another, you probably will need to implement the Factory pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern, so you inject the factory in your controller:

```
class RestartApiController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(RestartFactory $factory)
    {
        $this->restart = $factory->make('api');
    }

}
```

Comment: If I bind to AppOne though I will need to change the code to use the others, I need to be able to use different implementations based on a users input, will this still work?

Comment: Note that those are two different options, what you are describing is option 2, edited to clarify.

Comment: I keep getting an error saying "class not found" when using the factory make() function. any chance you could post an example for the factory, I may be missing something

Comment: seems to be a name spacing issue, it is requiring me to pass the class with a full namespace into the factory

Comment: if I call the `make` function in the controller how do I specify user input? there is no way from the route to pass user input into the controller is there?

Comment: User input? `Input::get()`?

Comment: in the constructor? if I have a route that takes parameters and one is the class i want to use, I cant set that in the constructor becuase the user supplied data is not available

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52788/discussion-between-antonio-carlos-ribeiro-and-arrowill12)